# Can I get a Schengen visa again easily ? (Pakistan)

Tags: pakistani-citizens

I went to the Czech Republic for a master's. I stayed there 2 years (2012-2014) and now I'm back to Pakistan. Can I get a Schengen tourist visa again easily? Or are there chances of rejection? Please also tell me what to do and what not to do. Thanks.

I heard that once you have student visa it becomes more easy as you were there for a long period. But once you are done with studies and be back home then the process changes. You have to show your source of income, professional status confirming your return. I did masters in film making. Now for example if my qualification is film making and im doing some other job like property documentation, so will that me a point for rejection too ?

One of my friend's friend (official in Czech embassy in Pakistan) told that the qualification and job must match otherwise it creates doubts. so here i am confused.

One more question: If my intention is to be there on a tourist visa and then search for job there, will that be easy ? or i have to apply first from my country and then follow the process e.g invitation letter from company, work visa etc ? or can i get work visa from there ? like change visa status from tourist to work ?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? You can get it easily. And there are chances of rejection.

Answer (score 3):

Your application for a Schengen visa will be considered on its own merits. As long as you can convince a visa officer that you have a valid reason to visit, and that you meet all other requirements, you will be given a visa. Otherwise, you will be denied a visa and will be told why.

Through your travel history, you have shown that in the past, you complied with visa conditions and did not attempt to overstay. Visa officers may take that into consideration, but will still evaluate your fresh application on its own merits.

In regard to looking for a job, I don't believe there's anything in the regulations stopping you from *searching* for a job on a visit visa. However, as I'm sure you're aware, you cannot work when you are on a visitor visa and thus, if you're offered a job during your stay, you'll have to obtain a work permit before you can begin working. The procedure to obtain such a permit is a matter of national policy and is different for each country, but I'm not aware of any Schengen country that will allow you to simply change your status from visitor to worker without having to return to your home country. It might be best to do some research and find out if this is possible for the country that you're thinking of.